# where is microsoft.visualbasic.dll for .net 3.5?

Tags: .net, sharepoint, dll

I am building a Sharepoint webpart, and I need to use the .net 3.5 microsoft.visualbasic.dll reference because Sharepoint uses .net 3.5.

Where can I find it?

I tried looking here, but can't find it

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5
```

I tried the .net 4.0 dll but the project didn't let me import it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not a v3.5 specific assembly, it is part of the core .NET assemblies.  So you'll find it in `c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v2.0.50727`, along with the other core assemblies like System.dll and mscorlib.dll.  v2.0.50727 is the runtime version of .NET framework versions 2.0 through 3.5 SP1, they all use the exact same CLR and core assemblies.

Different in .NET 4 and up, the reference assemblies are stored in a different home directory.  And they are internally different.  No longer a copy of the assembly in the GAC, they only contain metadata, no IL.  You'll find it in `c:\program files\reference assemblies\microsoft\framework\.netframework\v4.0`

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, you do not need to reference any visualbasic.dll explicitly if you go into the compile options of your project and set target framework to .net 3.5