# running vb.net code in Mono on Windows

Tags: vb.net, mono

I'm trying to run the following vb.net code on Mono on the Windows 7 machine, ina file called vbtest.vb:

```
console.writeline("hello world")
```

The command used and error:

```
C:\Windows\System32>vbnc "C:\Users\Henry\vbtest.vb"
Visual Basic.Net Compiler version 0.0.0.5943
Copyright (C) 2004-2010 Rolf Bjarne Kvinge. All rights reserved.

Error : VBNC2017: The library 'Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll' could not be found.
There were 1 errors and 0 warnings.
Compilation took 00:00:00.3320190
```

Comment: Find Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll?

Comment: Do you know where is is looking for it?  And why a generic Mono install doesn't include it, I thought it was a complete replacement for .NET

Comment: Mono is not a complete replacement for .NET, and also Mono on Windows is not up-to-date and troublesome. Thus, when you run VB.NET on Mono for Windows, you hit all the disadvantages.

Comment: so you need the official .NET runtimes on windows to run Mono?

Comment: vbnc doesn't find Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll even specifying the correct path (c:\windows\..., ref. http://stackoverflow.com/q/11937944/1315873) neither its gac version (lib path in mono install folder). I'll try to convert everything in c# since mcs seams better... don't count on SharpDevelop for convert your project if you have references and make use of "#if". That's my experience so far.